# Beginner: Is there another book?

Tags: arrl

Is there another book I can use to study for my test?
This ARRL Ham Radio License Manual book (Level 1 ) is HORRIBLE!
I never had electronics anything in school nor electricity. 
I got through the explanations about frequency even though I am still confused. One paragraph referred to a term that wasn't explained until the next page. DUH.
Then I got to the electronics section. OMG!!! It's horrible. One unfamiliar term after another after another with limited explanations.
I have absolutely no idea what this guy is talking about.
No wonder people get scared away.
If I can't find another way to learn this (no classes within 400 miles), I am just going to give up.
I haven't even gotten to the place where I learn how to use my radio yet.

Comment: You may benefit from the [ARRL Ham Radio License Support Page](http://www.arrl.org/ham-radio-license-manual). And you may be disappointed - the License Manual does not teach you how to actually use your radio. The License Manual focuses on the topics required to pass the license exam.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic because it is [a request for a shopping recommendation](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

I studied for my technician class exam using Gordon West's book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Technician-2014-2018-manual-HamStudy-software/dp/0945053800](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0945053800)
It basically just goes through each question in the question pool and explains how to understand the question. I studied for about a month, just memorizing each question and getting a basic understanding. You should also supplement your learning with [QRZ practice tests](http://www.qrz.com/hamtest/). Try to meet other people in your area and ask them lots of questions.

Comment: Thanks. I really *want* to understand this stuff but the explanations are so AAAARRRGGGG! horrible.

Comment: If I can add my $0.02, don't just use practice tests to study - that's not a study method, it's an ongoing "how am I doing?" benchmark. There are a few ham radio study websites out there that have actual study tools like flashcards, use one of those.  My site is https://hamstudy.org but hamexam.org also has decent ones.